# Pros/cons of a combined router & poe switch vs separate units?

Tags: routing, switch

My current setup is:

`modem -> router -> switch (with poe) -> Access point (ubiquiti)
                |                     -> security camera
                | 
                 -> other access point
                 -> PCs near the router`

I just got sonic fiber (gigabit), so I need to upgrade my router and switch from 10/100 to gigabit.

I can either buy a single unit that does both routing and switching, or I can by two separate units, similar to the setup I have now.

Aside from there being fewer wires, what are the pros / cons of a single unit vs two separate units?  (from a brief Amazon search, it seems that separates may be less expensive, but it may not be an apples-to-apples comparison)

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: I fail to see a good reason to close this. There's not even a mention of consumer grade device.

Comment: @JFL indeed, the devices in question are 'professional grade' - the routers and switches that I'm considering buying are Ubiquiti. In the past I used consumer grade gear, but it was too unreliable. The setup described above is exactly what I used to have for my small business.  All that said.. yes, this is for my home setup, so if that's the deciding factor then close the question. But please know that it's a home that aspires to be run to a professional standard using professional kit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pros:

- simpler cabling
- less encumbrance
- single point of administration

Cons:

- single point of failure
- cannot upgrade a single device at a time.
- can be trickier to troubleshoot

Depending of the devices chosen, the price could be a pro or a con.

Personally, I strongly prefer separate devices.

Comment: Several devices in a chain are **multiple** single points of failure - it's better to have a _single_ point of failure.

Comment: @Zac67 true an false. Depends on the topology. In a flat network,  or a combination of layer 3 switch for internal routing and separate router for Internet access, a failure of the Internet access router does not impact the ability of clients to talk with the servers, thus less impact, for example.

Comment: totally correct - with 'in a chain' I was implying that you require all of them at the same time, should've been more clear. ;-)